# CLLocation discrepancy between distances in app & google maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocation

I am fetching distance between 2 locations:

1. From Google Maps: Distance = 1.5 KM (Approx) (Correct)
2. From App using `CLLocation`: Distance  = 0.83 KM (Approx) (Not Correct)

Location coordinates are:

Current Location: 19.0174941,72.8557548 
Destination Location: 19.0205907,72.8540556

Below is the code which I am using to calculate the distance:

```
CLLocation *destination = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude doubleValue]  longitude:[longitude doubleValue]];
CLLocationDistance distance = [destination distanceFromLocation:currentLocation]/1000.0;
```

I am not able to understand why there is such a difference in both approaches. Can anyone guide me how can I get same distance from both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Google map with Google SDK gives you actual road distance, while CLLocation gives you distance between 2 co-ordinates considering it a straight line. So there this this difference.

Please check apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:).

> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing
>   a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The
>   resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account
>   specific altitude changes between the two locations.

Comment: That means we can never get the exact distance using CLLocation Manager?

Comment: @iYoung Please see what Apple docs says regarding this, I have updated the answer.